# How to move folders in command prompt merging folders with the same name and replacing files with the same name?

Tags: windows, replace, cmd, command-prompt, move

I'd like to move my program files and user documents from C:\Windows.old to C:\, completely replacing what's currently in C:. The old and new OSs on my computer are both windows 10, I just had to make a clean install because I couldn't get it to start after a restoration that went wrong. How can I do this operation using the command prompt at windows startup? Is there a command to do this : move, merge folders, replace files with the same name?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First, don't move program files just like that. Programs don't store data only here. Absence of this data might prevent some programs from running, especially licensed ones because they will think it's an attempt of running the executable directly on another computer. A better solution is to reinstall the programs, as it will put everything in the good place to make it is running OK.

Here's the command:

```
xcopy <Source> <Destination> /s /y
```

Replace `<Source>` and `<Destination>` with their appropriated values. Example:

```
xcopy C:\Windows.old\Users\David C:\Users\David /s /y
```

xcopy will ask if it is a file or folder destination. Answer that it is a folder by typing the appropriate letter.

**Explanations**:The `/s` command line switch means to copy the entire file and folder structure, while `/y` means to not ask when overriding files. If you want to look even more geeky, add `/f`.